# Move Object Only Touching The Screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When user touch to screen and remove the finger from screen, I move the object *up*,

When user touch to screen and hold the finger on screen, I move object to *right*.

The problem is, If user removes the finger from screen, object is still moving.

```
void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Detect the first click
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            totalDownTime = 0;
            clicking = true;    
        }

        // If a first click detected, and still clicking,
        // move object right
        if (clicking && Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            totalDownTime += Time.deltaTime;
            rigidBody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            if (totalDownTime >= 0.5f)
            {

                clicking = false;
                OnLongClick.Invoke();
                rigidBody.AddForce(Vector2.right * 200, ForceMode2D.Force);

            }
        }

        // If a first click detected, and we release before the
        // duration, move object up
        if (clicking && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            rigidBody.AddForce(Vector2.up * tapForce, ForceMode2D.Force);
            clicking = false;
        }
    }
```

**How can I move the object only while touching the screen?**

Comment: You should rather use [Touch Input](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileInput.html) and check the [`touch.phase`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-phase.html) (<- see a complete example there).

Comment: You should also look at [Touch.tapCount](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-tapCount.html) and [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/326253/strange-touch-behavior.html?_ga=2.51281068.469858046.1593410128-397009934.1590440912#answer-326285) for a more thorough explantion.